# two matrices in one paragraph

Tags: math-mode, matrices

```
\[
   
A =\begin{pmatrix}
        \dots a_1 \dots \\
             \vdots  \\
         \dots a_n \dots 
    \end{pmatrix} \in  F_{2}^{k} 
  
\]
```

above code generate this

[image]

But required output is

[image]

how can I get above two matrix in one line ?

Comment: erh, by keep writing?!? `\qquad\text{and}\qquad b= .... `

Comment: Note that the two blank lines in your example code as wrong and will crash the compilation.

Comment: @daleif thanks , Now I will get my required result

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep writing like this

```
$    A =\begin{pmatrix}
        \dots a_1 \dots \\
             \vdots  \\
         \dots a_n \dots 
    \end{pmatrix} \in  F_{2}^{k} $ and  $b=\begin{pmatrix}
    b1 \\
    \vdots\\
    bn
    \end{pmatrix} \in F_2^n$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How your solution will work in `displaymath` equation? See @daleif comment(s).